# Console.log and await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, console.log

I noticed that `console.log(await some_promise());` works fine but if I make my own log function it doesn't work and it says that await only works in async functions. But then how come it works in console.log() ? If console.log is async, then how come it works without promises too?

Comment: Please show the logic that is not working.

Answer (score 4):

> But then how come it works in console.log()

It doesn't. Arguments passed to a function are always evaluated **before** the function is called. I.e. `await some_promise()` is evaluated *before* `console.log` is called, not *in* it. `console.log` is not `async`. Your code is equivalent to

```
const result = await some_promise();
console.log(result);
```

or

```
some_promise.then(result => console.log(result))
```

`console.log` doesn't know anything about the fact that the value you pass to it came from a promise.

> If console.log is async, then how come it works without promises too?

An `async` function

1. returns a promise
2. allows you to use `await` to unwrap promises.

That's all. It doesn't restrict which values you can pass to it. So even if `console.log` was `async` you could pass any value to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way to print promise value....**

```
some_promise().then(console.log);
```